# Firebase Cloud Messaging AJAX POST in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, ajax, firebase, google-cloud-messaging, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have the following code for TESTING PURPOSES:

```
$.ajax({
  url: 'https://fcm.googleapis.com/v1/projects/[PROJECT]/messages:send',
  type: 'POST',
  headers:{
    "Authorization":"Bearer "+[Access Token from FireBase Auth]
  },
  contentType:"application/json",
  data: {
    "message":{
      "token": [TOKEN from messaging.getToken],
      "notification" : {
        "body" : "This is an FCM notification message!",
        "title" : "FCM Message",
        }
     }
  },
  success: function () { },
  error: function () { },
});
```

This always results in the following response with a 401()...

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": 401,
    "message": "Request had invalid authentication credentials. Expected OAuth 2 access token, login cookie or other valid authentication credential. See https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/devconsole-project.",
    "status": "UNAUTHENTICATED"
  }
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I would follow the docs closely: https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/js/first-message Make sure you are getting all the tokens correctly etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the docs we linked in comments: https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/js/first-message

Under **Retrieve Registration Token**, you see this code:

```
messaging.getToken().then(function(currentToken) {
    if (currentToken) {
       sendTokenToServer(currentToken);
       updateUIForPushEnabled(currentToken);
    } else {
        // Show permission request.
        console.log('No Instance ID token available. Request permission to generate one.');
        // Show permission UI.
        updateUIForPushPermissionRequired();
        setTokenSentToServer(false);
    }
}).catch(function(err) {
    console.log('An error occurred while retrieving token. ', err);
    showToken('Error retrieving Instance ID token. ', err);
    setTokenSentToServer(false);
});
```

You'll notice the `sendTokenToServer()` function, that's not their function, that's supposed to be yours. You call their `getToken()` and in the promise you take the result and send it up, would look like this:

```
function sendTokenToServer(currentToken) {
    $.post({
        url: 'yourServer.com/some_token_receiving_endpoint',
        type: 'post',
        data: {token: currentToken}
    });
}
```

Then on the server, you'd receive that, and store it, likely in a database, related to their profile information.

Then, either at that moment, or, at a later time, you can query your database for those you want to notify, grab that token, and in conjunction with your access token **stored securely on your server**, you can then send the notification from there.

Typically, NodeJS, PHP, Python, or Ruby. As events happen, or on a schedule, your server can send notifications like this:

```
<?php
// Get some http client service  for your language
$client = new GuzzleHttp\Client();

// Get your user or users (with their tokens that you've stored)
$user = Db.someQueryReturningUser();

// Your message
$jsonData = '{
    "message":{
        "token": [TOKEN from messaging.getToken],
        "notification" : {
            "body" : "This is an FCM notification message!",
            "title" : "FCM Message",
        }
    }
 }';

// Send Mesage
$client->post('https://fcm.googleapis.com/v1/projects/[PROJECT]/messages:send',
[ 
    'headers' => [
        'Authorization' => 'Bearer ' . [Access Token from FireBase Auth]
    ],
    'json' => $jsonData
]);
```

Answer (score 2):

In a very broad sense, what you're doing wrong is trying to call the FCM APIs from a web browser client.  FCM messages are intended to be sent from a backend server under your total control.  The authorization token that you need to send is going to effectively have admin privileges to send messages to any and all of your users, and **you don't want to give that up to clients**, as it's massive security issue.

From the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/auth-server):

> Requests sent to FCM from your app server or trusted environment must
>   be authorized. The FCM HTTP v1 API uses a short-lived OAuth 2.0 access
>   token generated for a service account associated with your Firebase
>   project. The legacy protocols use long-lived API keys retrieved from
>   the Firebase console. In both cases, you must add the required
>   credential to each message request sent to FCM.

In other words, you're not supposed to give clients access to send messages with your privileged service account credentials. The rest of that page of documentation describes how to actually do the world of authorizing the send request.

Comment: Then, what is the Auth Bearer key supposed to be?

Comment: https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/js/first-message You can use JS to generate the token, but you ultimately send that token to the app server, once it's up there, you can then do the work on the server.

Comment: The token is supposed to be sent to a server, I know. But I'm just trying to send a test message. How can I make that work?

Comment: Follow the instructions on the page you linked.

Comment: It can't be done in AJAX. You can use AJAX to send the token to your server, but your backend must be the one that makes the request you are trying to make in AJAX.. can't do it on front end.

Comment: POST https://fcm.googleapis.com/v1/projects/myproject-b5ae1/messages:send HTTP/1.1

Content-Type: application/json
Authorization: Bearer ya29.ElqKBGN2Ri_Uz...HnS_uNreA

{
  "message":{
    "token" : "bk3RNwTe3H0:CI2k_HHwgIpoDKCIZvvDMExUdFQ3P1...",
    "notification" : {
      "body" : "This is an FCM notification message!",
      "title" : "FCM Message",
      }
   }
}

Comment: In that request, what is supposed to take the place of ya29.ElqKBGN2Ri_Uz...HnS_uNreA? Is it the server key?

Comment: Ok, I'll try from the backend.